# Code reuse between different packages in Typescript lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have individual Lambda functions which share the same classes and at times similar dependencies.what is the right way to do the packaging and deploying.I come from Java background and Maven/Gradle are the de-facto tools used. I'm looking for something similar in node.js/Typescript.

Comment: For dependencies you should lambda layers. However for shared code it is a bit tricky to isolate one function per folder. In general I have an `index.ts` file at the root and then I import all the functions in there and reference it in my `template.yaml`.
With this approach unfortunately you will not have distinct package for each functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For shared dependencies/functionalities, you should leverage [AWS Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). It may be worthwhile for you to look into creating Node/Typescript Modules so that you can follow Node patterns for dependency management through NPM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , can you refer any links for Node/Typescript Modules ,I think its too broad when you say modules.

Comment: Sure, to create a node module check out https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-and-publish-your-first-node-js-module-444e7585b738. To create a lambda layer, check out https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e